# How to clear query result of a previous query?

Tags: mysqli, overlap

So I have these queries and in the last query the result I'm trying to get keeps getting replaced by the result of a previously successful query, I really don't know what to do. I've tried different methods to call the query and whatnot but it keeps bringing me the answer of the previous one. They're all on different pages, called upon by include_once.

This is the query I'm trying to get the result out of:

```html
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido  FROM socios WHERE nombreClub = ' " . $_SESSION["clubDetail"] . " ' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $nombreSocio = $row["nombre"];
  $apellidoSocio = $row["apellido"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

And this is the result I'm actually getting:

```html
try {
 
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=4h', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM club4h";
   if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
     if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

     /* Issue the real SELECT statement and work with the results */
      $sql = "SELECT id, nombreClub, liderVoluntario FROM club4h";
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
      $nombreClub[] = $row["nombreClub"];
      $liderVoluntario[] = $row["liderVoluntario"];
      $id[] = $row["id"];
      }
    }
    /* No rows matched -- do something else */
     else {
      print "No rows matched the query.";
    }
   }
   
 $res = null;
 $conn = null;
 $sql = null;
 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

```html
array (size=8)
  'nombre' => string 'jose' (length=4)
  0 => string 'jose' (length=4)
  'apellido' => string 'christian' (length=9)
  1 => string 'christian' (length=9)
  'titulo' => string 'lider voluntario' (length=16)
  2 => string 'lider voluntario' (length=16)
  'unidadProg' => string '362 - sabana grande' (length=19)
  3 => string '362 - sabana grande' (length=19)
```

If you need more code or more information ask me. Maybe it's easy but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting $result to NULL before starting new query as follow

```
$result =NULL;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: so you mean all those different queries in different files. are these all included by single page or one query can include_once other query? Because include_once ignores already included files. If that the case pages might not be included in the way you have expected.  What about print some test result? like printing the result values once it is fetched from database. $nombreSocio = $row["nombre"]; echo  $nombreSocio;

Comment: the page where i'm trying to display doesn't have the previous query files included, i only used "include_once" for the page of the query I'm trying to get the result. I used var dump on "$row" variable and the information it gives me is the last code snippet i posted above, otherwise the value of the variables is null.

Comment: might sessions have to do something about it?